# Find all Shorthest Paths between 262 Points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shortest-path

Is there anyway to find all shortest paths between 262 points in ArcMap ? I have tried to use new route analysis in ArcMap, but it did not work. I could not understand what is the problem. I am getting unlocated error for some CSD coordinates. [image]

Comment: Have a read of the help file, page "Types of network analysis layers". Sounds like OD matrix is what you are after?

Comment: Your screenshot makes it appear your data is not in a projected coordinate system. You might want to project it before you do any type of distance analysis.

Comment: Yes, I read. OD matrıx is giving straight line between points. This is not what I am looking for. By using road network file, I am trying to find all shorthest paths. @Hornbydd

Comment: But if actually _read the help file_ you will see it says "...Even though the lines are straight for performance reasons, they always store the network cost, not straight-line distance"

Comment: In the map I am seeing straight line, how I can reach shorthest road networks ?  @Hornbydd

Comment: Could you please explain what does that mean ? I am getting unlocated error for some points.  Do you think that am I using right tool ? @Mattropolis